# omp single doesn't work after looping for 10 times?

Tags: openmp

I am learning how to use !$omp single in openmp. In the program below, when wwwno is changing from 10 to 0 one by one, I would expect "region 1" be executed by one thread for each wwwno as I have used OMP SINGLE. This is true when wwwno changed from 10 to 2, but when wwwno had changed to 1, all the 4 threads executed the statement 'print *, " region 1?.... "' which is inside OMP SINGLE(see the output below). Could anyone kindly tell me why !$OMP SINGLE fail in my case? Thank you very much.

```
program test
use omp_lib
implicit none
integer:: t, wwwno, wwwno_init, updown, thread
real(8) :: Lnfactor, end_Lnfactor
logical :: His_flag, Right_flag

end_Lnfactor = 1.d-8
print *, "                 wwwno    thread   Lnfactor"

!$omp parallel private(wwwno, Right_flag, t, thread)

thread = omp_get_thread_num()

Do wwwno = 10, 0, -1

    !$omp barrier                   
    !$omp single
        print *, "region 1? ", wwwno, thread, Lnfactor
        Lnfactor = 1.d0
        Lnfactor = 2.d0 * Lnfactor
    !$omp end single
    !$omp barrier

    DO While(Lnfactor>end_Lnfactor)

    !$omp barrier
    !$omp single
        His_flag=.false.
        Lnfactor = 5.d-1 * Lnfactor     
    !$omp end single

        t=0

        DO While(His_flag .eqv. .false.)

            t=t+1           

            if (mod(t,1000)==0) then
            !$omp critical
                His_flag = .true.
            !$omp end critical
            endif

        ENDDO

    !$omp barrier
    ENDDO

!$omp barrier
Enddo

print *, "arrived, thread no =", thread
!$omp end parallel

End program
```

OUPUT on the screen:

```
                  wwwno      thread   Lnfactor
 region 1?           10           3  2.188457805988275E-314
 region 1?            9           2  7.450580596923828E-009
 region 1?            8           1  7.450580596923828E-009
 region 1?            7           2  7.450580596923828E-009
 region 1?            6           1  7.450580596923828E-009
 region 1?            5           2  7.450580596923828E-009
 region 1?            4           0  7.450580596923828E-009
 region 1?            3           1  7.450580596923828E-009
 region 1?            2           2  7.450580596923828E-009
 region 1?            1           2  3.725290298461914E-009
 region 1?            1           0   2.00000000000000
 region 1?            1           1   2.00000000000000
 region 1?            1           3   2.00000000000000
 region 1?            0           2  7.450580596923828E-009
 region 1?            0           3   2.00000000000000
 region 1?            0           1   2.00000000000000
 region 1?            0           0   2.00000000000000
 arrived, thread no =           2
 arrived, thread no =           3
 arrived, thread no =           1
 arrived, thread no =           0
```

Comment: Make sure that the `DO While(Lnfactor>end_Lnfactor)` loop executes the same number of iterations in each thread, otherwise the inner `single` construct might end up being mixed with the other `single` construct in some of the threads, which could produce the observed behaviour.

Comment: thanks for your reply. You see I have put several !$omp barrier at the end of do while loop, so each thread should execute the same number of iteration in the loop.

Comment: Barriers from different parts of the source code could interfere with one another, unlike critical sections that could be named differently in order to prevent such interference.

Comment: Just a minute ago, I put this code into different machines. I set all machines to use only 4 threads. And I found that machines which has 8 cores works well (ie region 1 is visited by one thread only for each wwwno), but machines with only 4 cores will give the same wrong answers as I posted above.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. For the barrier, you mean different threads could stopped at different barriers instead of stopping at the same barrier at some moment? For critical sections, you means if my program has two different parts that have use omp critical, then if 2 different threads arrive these two parts, they will go through that two parts one by one if I do not give two different names to these two critical sections?

Comment: Critical sections could be given names, e.g. `!$omp critical(foo)`. If one thread reaches critical section `foo` and another one reaches at the same time critical section `bar`, both will continue executing the critical sections at the same time since those are two different critical sections. Anonymous critical sections are given a special name and those are thus all one and the same critical section.

Comment: I guess I get your meaning about naming critical. However I check my code my putting a private counter for each thread to count the no of times that each thread loop in DO While(Lnfactor>end_Lnfactor) loop for each wwwno, and found that each thread execute the same no of iteration as the others. However when wwwno is change from 10 to 2, every times each thread take 28 iteration in DO While (Lnfactor>end_Lnfactor) loop, but when wwwno=1, each thread only take 25 iterations!! Then things go wrong. And again this happen only when I use a 4 cores machines to run.